# JSON response not working correctly

Tags: php, json

**So this is now fixed thank you to everyone that has tried to help me the problem lied with the webhost company that I was with, they has a anti-bot protection that does not allow API requests however they turned it off and works like a charm thank you...**

Hi Everyone i'm not sure if anyone could help me with this current problem im making a game in UE4 (Unreal Engine), and using a JSON Plugin, now when i created it all it was working on a localhost using (BitNami), but then I migrated it over to my Webhost and its not working, instead of getting my JSON response back I keep getting this error.

> LogVaRest: Response (200):

```
   <html>
   <body>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script><script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toStri
         ng(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("f9b00f3e868697192212c57f65c86932");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/"; document.cookie="referrer="+escape(document.referrer); location.href="http:
         //gametest.wwhost.ga/gameinfo.php?user=youtube&password=youtubelogin&ckattempt=1";
      </script>
      <noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript>
   </body>
</html>
```

However if I put the JSON string into the browser I get the result .

[Link To JSON String](http://gametest.wwhost.ga/gameinfo.php?user=youtube&password=youtube&stuff=login)

Result

```
{
"result":"success",
"regkey":"29cf47b512c72315e82d586b88fa4a2249ce27ae2a0fd67c40b13dae3e438b241b76e52e0d43e440f098e75ddc04d36457fb64feccbee5b70d4054408e2444aa",
"banned":"no"
}
```

If anyone can help that would be great

Comment: Is this the relevant bit `This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support`

Comment: Yea it says that but all im capturing is the JSON, im not using a browser as its getting the users details in the game engine

Comment: Wlll that looks like it is throwing javascript code at you, so I would expect that a browser would be required to run that

Answer (score 0):

It looks like website`s backend checks User-Agent before sending a response.
You can add User-Agent header to your request.

For example `User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.63 Safari/537.36`.

I guess for your plugin it will be something like this:

```
Request->SetHeader(
    TEXT("User-Agent"),
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.63 Safari/537.36"
);
```

Or if it's your website you can just disable this User-Agent request filter.

Comment: [Image][1]

So what would i put in the header name and the value 
  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/8BNmL.png

Comment: Well. I thought that's obvious =)
Name: "User-Agent".
Value: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.63 Safari/537.36".

Comment: Thanks ill give that a go

Comment: Stupid question, but have you put this block between `Construct Json Request` and `Apply URL`?

Comment: That's odd. Can't you edit the source code instead of using this builder?
You can also try setting `Name` to `TEXT("User-Agent")`.

Comment: So I gave it a go and still the same error [Image Link](http://imgur.com/FF3hGQi)